# Unity- passing different variables to GameObjects/Clones created inside loops?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Edit 3:

i have managed to work out what exactly  i'm attempting to do, and it only took 48 hours.. i need to create multiple objects, based on the same object, with different values. but i keep creating multiple objects that all get the same values.

```
 foreach (float a in ListA)
    {
       

        Instantiate(Example); //so here i have also tried creating new game objects, they are created but wont render. and behave the same way as clone anyway. (can see their positions in the paused editor)
        

           Example.transform.position = new Vector2(0f, up); // this works as i want it too.
           
           
           Example.GetComponent<NewBehaviourScript>().SetSpeed(Assets.Class1.random.Next(20, 70) * 1f, Assets.Class1.random.Next(20, 70) * 1f, Assets.Class1.random.Next(20, 70) * 1f); //THIS is the issue.. it is passing the random values, but its is only passing the SAME random values to each instance. i have tried to .Add but it will just add multiple of the same script to the new object/clones. Adding this. doesnt really seem to matter. 
        
        up = up + 40f;//works
       
    }
```

i've tried creating the gameobjects different ways.. but it doesn't really matter. i wont be using random values in the end, i'm just using them as a test to make sure each object gets different values in the end.

Comment: i have gotten as far as making this script work how i expect it to on a single game object. i just need a way to efficiently scale it up to do multiple game objects.

Comment: In unity you will have the prefab as a class variable, and each time you create an instance of that prefab (using Instantiate), store that instance into a list/variable.  Unfortunately your description does not lend itself well to reconstruction.  Perhaps you could write up a mock code with stub methods?  It is difficult to understand where exactly you are stuck and in need of help.

Comment: @hijinxbassist ive kind of worked out a plan.. right now i'm stuck at the instant.. i can instantiate 1 obj(possibly more). i tried placing the instantion in a foreach loop in the start.. my result is i get one game object that behaves as intended on screen. then another game object that just sits still. and i cant tell if there are multiple instance of that object or not all sitting on top of each other. the issue i am i working through right now, is they all spawn at the same position, despite having a variable for the vector2 x and y that adds +whatever to itself at the end of the loop.

Comment: You should be using `Vector3` for positions in 3d space. Y is the up axis.  You can pause unity while running and inspect the objects in the hierarchy to confirm how many objects are created and where they are.

Comment: ok so i have confirmed i am spawning multiple objects on the same position.

Comment: @hijinxbassist but its a 2d game. i've been moving everything around with vector2s.

Comment: right now i have  float x = 0f;
            GameObject obj = Instantiate(Obj);
            obj.transform.position = new Vector2(0f, x); };
                     
            x = x + 200f;

Comment: i've tried reworking it a bunch of times.. but they constantly spawn on each other (also ignore that curly bracket.. i just missed it when deleting something not relevant.

Comment: Please move the code you have into your question.  Use the code sample button to format it.  I suggest moving all of these description comments into your question as well.  This will help others help and keeps the comments lean.

Comment: what im getting from reading on and on.. is its not possible at all to instantiate with vector2 ever.. and absolutely has to instantiate with a vector3.

Comment: Unless the function param is Vector2, I would use Vector3 since it removes the ambiguity caused by the conversion of Vector2 to Vector3 (causing z of V3 to be unset/0).

Comment: i was wrong, my original code did work.. except i overlooked that i declared x inside the loop instead of out side, so i just kept resetting it to zero. i would add the code, but it kind of spans multiple classes in multiple folders, and its alot.. i'm just trying to work out the spawn thing right now.. for which i have basically zero and its keeps getting deleted and changed.

Comment: @hijinxbassist i have finally narrowed my issue down to a very specific problem, after 2 days of constant frustration, i started from scratch focusing one thing at a time. most of what i was attempting to do was actually correct. but i have edited my original question for exactly where i am running into a snag. at least now i know what the issue is.

Comment: This question isn't about [tag:unityscript], it is about [tag:c#]

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the result that is returned from the Instantiate command.

```
var instance = Instantiate(Example);
instance.transform.position = new Vector2(0f, up);
....
```

Currently you are modifying values on the prefab itself, and not the instantiated object, which is why you are not seeing the changes you intended to apply.

Comment: and i do that how? "this." doesn't work. i've been trying for about 16 hours..
i've tried setting the prefab to empty.. and using .Add to add the script, and it will add the script to each one, with new parameters.. but its adds like 20 of copies of the script to the prefab.

Comment: didnt notice you edited the code thought you just quoted.. but that didn't work either.

Comment: so i've tried a lot of thing in the past few hours.. IF i give it a name, and create them as a new gameobject, and then add the script via add component, only the clones are affected and not the prefab.. BUT they ALL still get passed the same values. its like the loop isnt looping, and creating them one by one, but instead just dumping them all out at the same exact time.

Answer (score 0):

soooooo.. my code worked all along.. after many many hours, i gave up. literally threw in the towel and was going to go to sleep. and as soon as my head hit the pillow.. "what if..."

anyway, the problem was static modifiers in the NewBehaviorScript portion. i fell really dumb now. but for anyone else with this issue.. check your sub script for static modifiers.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).